# Are the following standard ways of using katakana?

Tags: colloquial-language, katakana

> あなたの得意なスパニッシュフードを教えてください！私はそれを作ることにトライしたい。

スパニッシュフード (Spanish food).

トライ (try).

I'm a bit surprised, because I'm almost sure that there are no-katakana equivalents for words like food and try.

Is this a standard way of using katakana? Or the speaker is using more katakana than usual to sound more "Englishly"?

(Another one: ハードだろう)

Comment: Was `あなたの得意なスパニッシュフードを教えてください！私はそれを作ることにトライしたい。` written by a native Japanese speaker..??

Comment: @Chocolate Yes, it was. A Japanese person from Hokkaido. I'm 100% sure, because I personally know the person.

Comment: 普通は「あなたの得意なスペイン料理を教えてください！」とか「それを作ることに挑戦したいです/私も作ってみたいです」とか言うんじゃないですかね・・

Comment: @Chocolate Yes, I was expecting that. But this is a native Japanese speaker ... maybe the person is trying to use more katakana than usual.

Comment: そうですね、カタカナ（外来語）を使ったほうがわかりやすいだろうと思ったのかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 5):

First, it is not common ***at all*** to say 「スパニッシュフード」.  We would mostly use 「スペイン料理{りょうり}」 or 「スペインの食{た}べ物{もの}」.

It sounds to me like this person was talking to a non-Japanese person who does not know much Japanese.  (Is s/he speaking to **you**, perhaps?)  The sentence itself would be very unnatural if said by one native speaker to another.

For how we would often phrase these, see @Chocolate's excellent comment above.

「トライ」, on the other hand, is quite common.  This is a fairly natural usage here.

「ハードだろう」 is not so strange, either, but again, I feel a "reason" for the word choice, especially after seeing 「スパニッシュフード」.

Comment: Oh, I see. Then my suspicions are correct. Yes, the person was speaking to me.